# Changing the PDF FONT'S (DJANGO)

Tags: css, django, pdf, fonts

I have a project in django, and i want to render some text to pdf. It's already working but now i need to change my font. I have `Gotham` font install on pc , and i use for all my documets , but right now i want to render my pdf with `Gotham` font's.

I download the font and put inside of my `templates` folder:

```html
myproject/
     |-- myproject
     |-- templates/
          |-- admin/
          |-- font/
              |-- GothamBookItalic.ttf
              |-- GothamBookLight.ttf
              |-- GothamBookLIghtItalic.ttf
              |-- GothamBookMedium.ttf
```

And this is my css of my `html`

```html
@font-face {
                font-family: GothamMedium;
                src: url('/font/GothamMedium.ttf') format('truetype'); 
            }
```

but is not working , and i have no idea what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Gotham webfont. Which should be a `.woff` file.

You do try to use `.ttf` TrueTypeFont. Which is not suited for modern web applications.

Here an example how this could look like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamMedium';
    src: url('fonts/GothamMedium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Could also look like this for a wider browser compatibility:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamMedium';
  src: url('fonts/GothamMedium-webfont.eot?') format('eot'),
  url('fonts/GothamMedium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/GothamMedium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/GothamMedium-webfont.svg#webfontdSscXrwb') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Maybe this is what you will look for: https://gist.github.com/mfd/f3d96ec7f0e8f034cc22ea73b3797b59

Comment: i try the gothamPro, and download the file .woff, and put inside of my `fonts` folder , and nothing. And also try to put the `link of css ` inside of the `<head>` and still nothing